# Proper way to lock the queue in a block device driver while serving requests

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a device driver for a network attached hard disk. and I am wondering what is the proper way to lock/unlock the requests queue and where?

To clarify:

1. I created a queue using the `blk_init_queue` and passed to that function the request handler function and a lock (i.e. semaphore) that I created.
2. My request handler function looks like this:

   ```
   struct request *req;
   int ret;
   while ((req = blk_fetch_request(q)) != NULL) {
        ret = rb_transfer(req);
   }
   ```
3. My `rb_transfer` starts a new kernel thread to handle the request.
4. Once the request is handled and the data transfer is done, `blk_end_request_cur` is called on that request.

Now, my question is how to protect access to the request queue in the loop above? and in the driver in general?

I tried something like this:

```
struct request *req;
int ret;
while ((req = blk_fetch_request(q)) != NULL) {
     spin_lock(&lock);
     ret = rb_transfer(req);
     spin_unlock(&lock);
}
```

But this failed and caused a kernel lock up.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try using `spin_lock_irqsave()` function. The queue lock has to be taken when irq's are disabled as the request function can be called in interrupt context. It's upto the user to use the spinlock as and when necessary to protect the requests. They lock is taken while processing the requests. Also, a `spinlock` has to be passed as the second argument to `blk_init_queue`, not a `semaphore`.

Comment: Take a look at some of the block drivers in the linux kernel for examples of how to protect your requests in the request queue.

Comment: Another questions is, what and where is 'lock' inside your request function ?

Comment: the lock is the same as queue->queue_lock. This should be the same lock sent passed to the 'blk_init_queue' function.

Answer (score 3):

The `request_fn` that you pass to `blk_init_queue` is called by holding the `spinlock` passed as the second argument and interrupts disabled. Hence, you can safely assume that no parallel threads are running that are executing this `request_fn`. However, if you create a parallel thread that processes this request, then synchronizing access to the requests in those threads are entirely your responsibility.

The `request_fn` is called by `__blk_run_queue_uncond` which is inturn called by functions `__blk_run_queue` and `blk_execute_rq_nowait` . If you search for functions calling `__blk_run_queue` in the linux kernel, you can see that all of them do so by holding the `q->queue_lock` which is the spinlock passed to function `blk_init_queue`.